# PowerApps unable to get value of SharePointIntegration.Selected, but only when using from a particular SharePoint Online view

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps-forms

We have a SharePoint Online list with an associated PowerApps custom form.  The list also has multiple views.

When a user tries to open the PowerApps form a particular view on this list, the PowerApps form opens on the right side of the SharePoint page, but opens the wrong list item.  The user always sees the 1st item in the list, regardless of which list item they actually selected/double-clicked in SharePoint.

To investigate, I determined that the SharePoint form's "Item" value is set to:

> If(IsBlank(SharePointIntegration.Selected) ||
> IsEmpty(SharePointIntegration.Selected),First([@'data']),SharePointIntegration.Selected)

When troubleshooting, I tried changing the SharePoint form's "Item" value to simply the following:

> SharePointIntegration.Selected

However, the form would then get stuck on the 'Getting your data...' message, and never loads.  This led me to believe that the PowerApps form simply couldn't get the selected item from SharePoint, but only when working from a particular SharePoint list view.

If the user switches to a different view on this same list, they can then open and work with the PowerApps form, and it gets the correct record every time.

Can anyone provide some guidance on what to check next, or is this potentially a bug?

Comment: I would start looking into what is unique about that particular SharePoint view. Once you know that, see if you can replicate the issue by creating another view with the same configuration. Then try changing your view, one setting at a time until the SharePointIntegration.Selected starts working. If you can identify exactly what is breaking it, you may be able to work why and/or how to fix it.